# Diference between Specific,perceived and perceptual Loudness

Tags: audio, acoustics

i came across many terms describing loudness ! I understood perceived loudness which is what the user perceived and is related to the user. What is specific loudness and perceptual loudness?

`AES Convention Paper 7180` defines specific loudness as

> a measure of perceptual intensity across frequency and time and is measured in units of sone per critical band

which i confuse with perceptual loudness! Can someone make me clear?